# Including Table Containers in DT::datatable in R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, datatables, dt

I'm new to HTML and interactive tables, and I'm having trouble building a table container to add headers for my data set. Is there an easy way to insert table headers for my data set? I want columns 2-5 (excluding date in column 1) and columns 6-9 to have header 'Sector' and 'Industry' respectively.

I've included an extract of the dataset below.

Thank you!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

df <- structure(list(date = c("1975 Q1", "1975 Q2", "1975 Q3", "1975 Q4", 
"1976 Q1", "1976 Q2"), Sector = c("Accommodation Food Services", 
"Accommodation Food Services", "Accommodation Food Services", 
"Accommodation Food Services", "Accommodation Food Services", 
"Accommodation Food Services"), industry = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Goods", "Ownership", "Services"), class = "factor"), 
    Sector_GDP = c(112.4, 110.7, 116.6, 123.4, 125.1, 120.7), 
    sector_GDP_change = c(0, -0.0151, 0.0533, 0.0583, 0.0138, 
    -0.0352), goods_producing_industries = c(1014.2, 1090.9, 
    1205.7, 1269.6, 1166.6, 1247.6), services_producing_industries = c(1991.7, 
    2019.6, 2105.2, 2206.6, 2154.2, 2156.5), total_GDP = c(3087.1, 
    3194, 3396.9, 3562.9, 3409.4, 3493.4), industry_GDP_change = c(0, 
    0.0346, 0.0635, 0.0489, -0.0431, 0.0246)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(industry = structure(3L, .Label = c("Goods", 
"Ownership", "Services"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

DT::datatable(df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.5      
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Australia/Melbourne         
#>  date     2020-09-04                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.1.9   2020-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  blob          1.2.1   2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  broom         0.7.0   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.3   2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  colorspace    1.4-1   2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crosstalk     1.1.0.1 2020-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  curl          4.3     2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
#>  DBI           1.1.0   2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  dbplyr        1.4.4   2020-05-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.2   2020-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  DT          * 0.15    2020-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.0   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.2   2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  haven         2.3.1   2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  hms           0.5.3   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmlwidgets   1.5.1   2019-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  httr          1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  jsonlite      1.7.0   2020-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lifecycle     0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lubridate     1.7.9   2020-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  mime          0.9     2020-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pillar        1.4.6   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.3   2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.5   2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  readr       * 1.3.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  readxl        1.3.1   2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  reprex        0.3.0   2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rvest         0.3.6   2020-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  scales        1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.4.6   2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tibble      * 3.0.3   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyr       * 1.1.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.0   2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  vctrs         0.3.4   2020-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  webshot       0.5.2   2019-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.16    2020-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xml2          1.3.2   2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this produce what you want?

```
# a custom table container
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
   class = 'display',
   thead(
      tr(
         th(rowspan = 2, 'date'),
         th(colspan = 4, 'Sector'),
         th(colspan = 4, 'Industry')
      ),
      tr(
         lapply(names(df)[-1], th)
      )
   )
))
print(sketch)

DT::datatable(df, container = sketch, rownames = FALSE)
```

[image]

Adapted from Section 2.6
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/